# Comparing strings in Java

Tags: java, android, string

Im trying to compare the values of two edittext boxes. What i would like is to just compare passw1 = passw2. As my code is now comparing two strings i have entered as i could not get to compare them.

```
 final EditText passw1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passw1);
 final EditText passw2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passw2);
 Button buttoks = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Ok);
      buttoks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    

    public void onClick(View v) {       

     if (passw1.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1234") && passw2.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1234")){
      Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Username and password match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Username and password doesn't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
     }   });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[EDIT]
I made a mistake earlier, because, to get the text, you need to use .getText().toString().

Here is a full working example:

```
package com.psegina.passwordTest01;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    LinearLayout l;
    EditText user;
    EditText pwd;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        l = new LinearLayout(this);
        user = new EditText(this);
        pwd = new EditText(this);
        btn = new Button(this);

        l.addView(user);
        l.addView(pwd);
        l.addView(btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        setContentView(l);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        String u = user.getText().toString();
        String p = pwd.getText().toString();
        if( u.equals( p ) )
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Matches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getText()+" != "+pwd.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Original answer (Will not work because of the lack of toString())

Try using .getText() instead of .toString().

```
if( passw1.getText() == passw2.getText() )
#do something
```

.toString() returns a String representation of the whole object, meaning it won't return the text you entered in the field (see for yourself by adding a Toast which will show the output of .toString())

Comment: i tried this but all i get is they do not match even when they are

Comment: Can you post the code block with getText() and the output of Log.d("test", passw1.getText()) and Log.d("test", passw2.getText())?

Comment: Also, you can try the following: if( (passw1.getText()).equals(passw2.getText()) )

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {       
        if( passw1.getText() == passw2.getText() ){
         Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Username and password match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
         
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Username and password doesn't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }}

Comment: I edited the answer with a full working example that should do what you are asking for.

Comment: @mrPer I edited the answer because there was a typo in the last example, using == instead of equals().

Answer (score 35):

Using the == operator will compare the references to the strings not the string themselves.

Ok, you have to toString() the Editable. I loaded up some of the code I had before that dealt with this situation.

```
String passwd1Text = passw1.getText().toString();
String passwd2Text = passw2.getText().toString();

if (passwd1Text.equals(passwd2Text))
{
}
```

Comment: i tried that and i still have else msg come up when they are matching

Answer (score 6):

In onclik function replace first line with this line u will definitely get right result.

**if (passw1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1234") && passw2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1234")){**

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the values using `equals()` of Java :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    s1=text1.getText().toString();
    s2=text2.getText().toString();

    if(s1.equals(s2))
        Show.setText("Are Equal");
    else
        Show.setText("Not Equal");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need both getText() - which returns an Editable and toString() - to convert that to a String for matching.
So instead of: `passw1.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1234")`
you need `passw1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1234")`.

Answer (score 1):

ou can use String.compareTo(String) that returns an integer that's negative (<), zero(=) or positive(>).

Use it so:

You can use **String.compareTo(String)** that returns an integer that's negative (<), zero(=) or positive(>).

Use it so:

```
  String a="myWord";
  if(a.compareTo(another_string) <0){
    //a is strictly < to another_string
  }
  else if (a.compareTo(another_string) == 0){
    //a equals to another_string
  }
else{
  // a is strictly > than another_string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.trim()` first, before `.equals()`, or create a new String var that has these things.

Answer (score 0):

did the same here needed to show "success" twice 
response is data from PHP

```
 String res=response.toString().trim;

                            Toast.makeText(sign_in.this,res,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if ( res.compareTo("success")==0){
    Toast.makeText(this,res,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a proper answer to the question

Comment: try
**string res = response.toString().trim()**

Answer (score 0):

```
String password=passw1.trim();
if (password.equalsIgnoreCase("1234")){
      Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Username and password match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You need to use the `trim` method in the String