# Very weird behaving in "IF STATEMENT" in Android

Tags: java, android, loops, if-statement

Anybody ever seen the following statement running false ?

```
String BloodyHell = "Unbelievable";
if (BloodyHell == BloodyHell) >> false
```

Although instead of bloody hell, I've got: `|-,-|` or `|o,-|` or `|-,o|` or `|o,o|` or `XXXX`.

None of these comes TRUE though. While debugging the exact thing is still false.

Somebody please help me out here. Here's the snippet:

```
public String doStats()
{       
        String[] pattern = splitPattern();          
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++)
        {
            if (pattern[i] == "|-,-|")
                frontClosed++;
            if (pattern[i] == "|o,-|")
                left++;
            if (pattern[i] == "|-,o|")
                right++;
            if (pattern[i] == "|o,o|")
                frontOpened++;
            if (pattern[i] == "XXXX")
                noFace++;           
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4700501/1052673

Comment: You need to be careful of the broad examples you make. `BloodyHell == BloodyHell` will *always* be true: http://ideone.com/ag6A29

Comment: I believe the first thing they talk about in Java books and tutorials is about the use of `equals()` and explaining the reasons for it? re. question poster

Answer (score 3):

In Java you should use the [`String#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to compare string values instead of `==`.  The `==` operator compares object references to see if they are the same object, which is why you keep getting `false`.  The object references are different, even if the contents of the strings are equivalent.

```
if (pattern[i].equals("|-,-|"))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between `==` and `equals()`.

When comparing strings, you want to use `equals()`; `==` is used to compare if they are the same thing in memory.